# Underdetermined System and Minimizing Cost

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I need to minimize 4x + 4y subject to the following constraints:

$4x + 8y = 40$

$x + 2y = 10$

Any ideas? Answers must be integers, as they represent physical units.

Comment: What physical unit is that which is integer only? Pieces?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graphical approach. Each red dot represents an integer solution. The dots are labelled with the corresponding values of the objective (cost) function $4x+4y$. The only allowable ones are the ones on the thick blue line, which is the line $x+2y=10$. You can see that the one with minimum value of $4x+4y$ is the one at the top left. It has $x=0$, $y=5$, and cost $= 20$.[image: picture].

This picture shows a number of other things that might be of interest, too:

- It gives you the maximum cost (40) down at the bottom right
- It helps you understand the constraint $x+ 2y \le 20$ (the yellow triangle)
- You can see where the cost is constant (along each dashed line)
- You can see how moving the dashed lines left/down decreases cost
- You can see that increasing either $x$ or $y$ by 1 has the same effect on cost (because the dashed lines are at 45 degrees)
- You can see how optimal solutions will typically lie at "vertices" of the triangle (because they will be points of contact with some dashed line)

Comment: How did you make this beautiful diagram?

Comment: > How did you make this beautiful diagram? Powerpoint

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Your two constraints are equivalent.

Hint 2: There is no optimum.

Comment: I can see that x = 10 - 2y. Do you think it's sufficient to just use trial by error with values of y to then find that when y = 3 and x = 4, cost is 28, or is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: I'm not so sure about hint 2.

Comment: @CommonerG $x=10-2y$, thus we want to minimize $40-4y$. Clearly, this has no optimum over the integers. Just take $y$ as large as possible.

Comment: @Abel I see our disconnect. Since this is a cost minimization problem, I have implicitly assumed non-negativity constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Notice first that the two constraints are the same line. We can ignore one of them.

Any solution must satisfy $x+2y=10$ but minimize $4x+4y$.

Next, note that the "price" of $x$ and $y$ are the same. Adding some to $x$ or some to $y$ have the same effect on cost.

However, increasing the value of $x+2y$ is "cheaper" using $y$ since $y$  is more "productive". A unit of y adds 2 to the value $x+2y$ at the cost of $4$ while adding a unit of $x$ adds only 1 to the value at the cost of $4$.

Thus, the solution to your problem is to use only $y$ so that $y=5$

Comment: Thank you, this was a really clear explanation!